# Корректное подключение перехватчиков (hooks) в GIt

Tags: git, git-commit, githooks

В гите есть специальный инструмент - перехватчики (hooks). Это определенные сценарии, которые запускаются в определенные моменты. Находятся они в папке ".git/hooks". У меня возник вопрос, на который я так и не смог найти ответ. Я хочу задать свой хук - если точно, то такой, который будет удалять пробелы в конце строк во время коммита. Я уже нашел код для перехватчика, но не могу понять, что с ним делать. Куда закинуть? Как подключить? Каким образом сделать хук не у меня на компьютере, а на гите, чтобы все коммиты таким образом обрабатывались?

Comment: «на гите» — это в том числе и «у вас на компьютере»: все копии одного хранилища равноценны.

Comment: а вообще, видимо, у вас настал тот ключевой в жизни момент, когда следует наконец прочесть [документацию](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git).